# What to use for classification with boosted decision trees in R?

Tags: r, tree, classification

I'm rather new to R. I have found ways to run classification using trees with bagging (randomforest), and ways to run regression with boosting (gbm), but what I'm looking for is to do classification using boosting.

Supposedly, gbm is able to do this when the target variable consists of 0s and 1s and when you set Bernoulli as the function -- but no, the results that I get still point to regression being used.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I have removed some tags that were completely unrelated to the question. Please read tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xgboost within the caret package you might have to also change both the `objective = binary:logistic` and the `eval_metric =` to reflect your classification needs.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes classification if you transform the predicted values to 0 and 1. For example with round(). That is, using a threshold of 0.5. But there are more sophisticated approaches to finding the optimal threshold.